# How do you make the camera focus on flutter mobile_scanner 2.0.0 in Android?

Tags: flutter, qr-code

I'm using mobile_scanner 2.0.0 in Flutter on an Android 23 SDK phone. When I try to read a QR code the camera does not try auto focus so its difficult to read small QR codes.

Answer (score 0):

The package uses the default autofocus setting of the device you are using. If your device has trouble auto focussing, I think it will be a problem of the device itself.